# How to add a substring at specific positition in Lua

Tags: string, lua

I am new to Lua language and I want add a substring at specific postion within a string..like I want to save a file every time with a new name. My file is stored in "name.extension" format.What I want is to add a counter each time the file generate so that it is stored with  a new name every time like "name1.extension" and next time "name2.extension" etc. I just need to see the dot position and then add counter before this dot...
Can anybody help me here?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the easy way is [using string.format](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-string.format)

```
base = 'name'
ext = 'extension'
template = base..'%d.'..ext
print(template:format(10))
-- or shorter
print(('name%d.extension'):format(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
template = "name.extension"
n = 23
print(template:gsub("%.",n.."."))
```

or

```
template = "name<number>.extension"
n = 23
print(template:gsub("<number>",n))
```